# Waiting till an asynchrous method completes. (Function returning IAsyncResult )

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, .net-4.5, async-await

I have a webservice and this particular function:

```
IAsyncResult func(object signature, AsyncCallback callBack, object asyncState)
```

I can understand that the sole purpose of using await is not to block the UI while a very long operation takes place
and also it has some callback function that could be used to perform the results of the "func"

In my case, I have to wait (must wait) until I get the result of the func.

Any suggestions how should i wait till I get the result of func (in other words, just hang on until i get the result)

**EDIT:**

Why should I do that ?

I just want to check if the signature is of particular type. If so, the function stops executing and returns 0.
This is the only functionality I required from func and do not see worth defining a call back method and an state object.

Comment: Should I use WaitOne ?

Comment: You don't have to wait. There are some situations where it *seems* like you have to wait. Describe your situation and we'll help you find an alternative to waiting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you describe is the Asynchronous programming model that predates Tasks and is used extensively in .NET up to v. 3.5. This is the model used by all the BeginXXX/EndXXX method pairs.

You can [convert APM calls to TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423.aspx) tasks using the [FromAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync.aspx) method. The following example comes from the documentation and creates a Task from the FileStream BeginRead and EndRead methods.

BeginRead has a signature similar to func:

```
 IAsyncResult BeginRead(byte[] array,int offset,
    int numBytes,
    AsyncCallback userCallback,
    Object stateObject)
```

You can convert it to a Task like this:

```
Task<int> task = Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(
        fs.BeginRead, fs.EndRead, data, 0, data.Length, null);
```

Once you have a task, you can await it:

```
var bytes = await Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(
        fs.BeginRead, fs.EndRead, data, 0, data.Length, null);
```